# displaying dynamic form in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to insert and delete fields in a dynamic form, but it gives me an error on the `formArrayName` in the component-html. I really don't know what to do. Thanks.

this is the problem on console:

```
in.ts:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'ttp_form'
    at _throwError (forms.mjs:3151:11)
    at setUpFormContainer (forms.mjs:3133:9)
    at FormGroupDirective._setUpFormContainer (forms.mjs:4914:9)
    at FormGroupDirective.addFormArray (forms.mjs:4827:14)
    at FormArrayName.ngOnInit (forms.mjs:5123:28)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2450:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2419:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2370:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9075:17)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9058:5)

main.ts:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'controls')
    at HeroFormComponent_Template (hero-form.component.html:6:34)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10457:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10342:13)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11401:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10132:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10392:13)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11401:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10132:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10392:13)
    at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:11545:9)
```

this is my-component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="ttp_form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="ttp_form">
      <div *ngFor="let child of ttp_form.get('sottotecnica')['controls']; index as i"
      formGroupName="{{i}}">
              <!--Tattica-->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="tattica">Tattica</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="tattica" formControlName="tattica">
                  <option *ngFor="let tat of tattiche" [value]="tat">{{tat}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <!--Tecnica-->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="tecnica">Tecnica</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="tecnica" formControlName="tecnica">
                  <option *ngFor="let tec of tecniche" [value]="tec">{{tec}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <!--Sotto-Tecnica-->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="sottotecnica">Sotto-Tecnica</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="sottotecnica" formControlName="sottotecnica">
                  <option *ngFor="let sot of sottotecniche" [value]="sot">{{sot}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              
              
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="addField()">Aggiungi TTP</a>
              <br>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="removeField(i)">Rimuovi TTP</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!ttp_form.valid">Invia</button>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

this is my-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-hero-form',
templateUrl: './hero-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./hero-form.component.css']
})

export class HeroFormComponent implements OnInit {

ttp_form: FormGroup | any

constructor(){ }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.ttp_form = new FormArray([
new FormGroup({
tattica: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
tecnica: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
sottotecnica: new FormControl(null)
})
])

}

addField() {
const control = <FormArray>this.ttp_form.controls["sottotecnica"]
control.push(
new FormGroup({
tattica: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
tecnica: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
sottotecnica: new FormControl(null)
})
);
}

removeField(index){
const control = <FormArray>this.ttp_form.controls['sottotecnica'];
control.removeAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining ttp_form as a FormArray in your component but using it as a FormGroup in your template. You need to update the ttp_form variable to be a FormGroup instead of a FormArray to fix the error.

You could iterate through your formArray first, and then have the form:

```js
<div *ngFor="formgroup of ttp_form">
 <form [formControl]="formgroup">...</form>
<div>
```

With this you have multiple forms.

Whats also possible is, to wrap your current FormArray inside another FormGroup:

```js
this.ttp_form = new FormGroup({
  sottotecnica: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      tattica: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      tecnica: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      sottotecnica: new FormControl(null)
    })
  ])
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for you help, I couldn't done it with the first option but with the second it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As Don mentioned, you need to nest the `FormArray` inside a `FormGroup`. Since your form array is composed of one or many form groups you will have to use `formGroupName="{{ i }}"` in your template to render the form properly. Here's an example from the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms) that I modified to use an array of form groups.

The component:

```
// imports omitted for brevity

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ["", Validators.required],
      lastName: [""],
      addresses: this.fb.array([
        this.createAddressFormGroup()
      ])
    });
  }

  get addresses() {
    return this.form.get("addresses") as FormArray;
  }

  createAddressFormGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
      street: [""],
      city: [""],
      state: [""],
      zip: [""]
    });
  }

  addAddress() {
    this.addresses.push(this.createAddressFormGroup());
  }

  removeAddress(index: number) {
    this.addresses.removeAt(index);
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

The template:

```
<form class="flex-column" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="firstName">First name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastName" formControlName="lastName" />
    </div>

    <div class="flex-column" formArrayName="addresses">
      <div *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">
        <fieldset class="flex-column">
          <legend>Address</legend>
          <div class="form-field" formGroupName="{{ i }}">
            <label for="street-{{ i }}">Street</label>
            <input id="street-{{ i }}" type="text" formControlName="street" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-field" formGroupName="{{ i }}">
            <label for="city-{{ i }}">City</label>
            <input id="city-{{ i }}" type="text" formControlName="city" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-field" formGroupName="{{ i }}">
            <label for="state-{{ i }}">State</label>
            <input id="state-{{ i }}" type="text" formControlName="state" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-field" formGroupName="{{ i }}">
            <label for="zip-{{ i }}">Zip</label>
            <input id="zip-{{ i }}" type="text" formControlName="zip" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <button (click)="removeAddress(i)">Remove address</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="button" (click)="addAddress()">+ Add address</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex">
      <button type="submit" (click)="handleSubmit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-dynamic-form-mn5rn9?file=/src/app/app.component.html:53-1793) if you would like to see it in action.

Hope this helps.